# Piping output to local machine in a loop

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I am trying to read some files located on a server and write only a certain number of columns from those files onto my local machine. I am tried to do this in a for loop to avoid inputting my password for each file. Below is what I was able to cobble till now.

The following code works but writes all the output to a single file which is not manageable due to its large size.

```
ssh user@xx.xxx.xxx.xx 'for loc in /hel/insur/*/201701*; do zcat $loc | grep -v NUMBER | awk -F',' -v OFS="," '\''{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}'\'' | gzip; done'  > /cygdrive/c/Users/user1/Desktop/test/singlefile.csv.gz
```

So, I tried to write each file individually as shown below but it gives me an error saying that it cannot find the location(possibly because I am sshed ito the remote server).

```
ssh user@xx.xxx.xxx.xx 'for loc in /hel/insur/*/201701*; do zcat $loc | grep -v NUMBER | awk -F',' -v OFS="," '\''{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}'\'' | gzip > /cygdrive/c/Users/user1/Desktop/test/`echo $loc | cut -c84-112` ; done'
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: save the files remotely and then move them locally

Comment: Yes. I can do that or I can pipe all the output to a single file into the local machine and then break it up. But, those two approaches involve an extra step. I was wondering if there is another way to do it in a single step (something like I was trying to do in the posted question).